# How to efficiently clone a Rust ndarray from a view?

Tags: multidimensional-array, view, rust, clone, slice

I've created a 1D row view of a 2D ndarray and I'd like to clone the contents.  Currently, I'm doing it like this:

```
let mut row_orig = table.subview_mut(Axis(0), chosen_row);
// ...
// some operations on row_orig
// ...
let mut row_copy = Array1<f32>::zeros(table.cols());
row_copy.assign(&row_orig);
```

It seems slightly inefficient to create and initialize with zeros and then
perform the copy.  Plus, I have to declare `row_copy` as mutable when it doesn't need to be. Is there a better way? Apparently, `.clone` doesn't exist for ndarray views.

I thought that using a slice might be the solution, but I'm running into a mutable/immutable problem with this code:

```
let row_copy = table.slice(s![chosen_row,..]).clone();
// do something mutable with table
```

Comment: _"but I'm running into a mutable/immutable problem"_ please produce a [MCVE] of that particular issue, so that we can provide better insights on that particular attempt. Adding some minimal code which produces `table` and `chosen_row` would help too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'd like to clone the contents.

If that is the case, then you do not want just to clone the array view (which would have been just a shallow copy). You want a uniquely owned array with the same contents as another array. That can be done with [`to_owned`](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.12.0/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#method.to_owned).

```
let row_orig = table.subview(Axis(0), chosen_row);
let row_copy = row_orig.to_owned();
```